# Java do while loop keeps loop even it not meets the condition

Tags: java, do-while

My `while(cur!=head)` is supposed to execute at node4, since it starts
 at node3, the program executes the statement in `do` block at least once , then it will read at node4, node4 is same to head node which is node3.

My program is supposed to return.

```
 Actual output: 3 3 3 3 4 5 1 2 

 Expected output: 3 3 3 4 5 1 2 3
```

The actual output is correct, my expected output is wrong.However, I
 am just wondering, when cur is equal to head, which not qualify to the
 condition `while(cur!=head)`, but it can keep running? Why?

```
class LinkedNode
{
    int val;
    LinkedNode next;
    LinkedNode (int x)
    {
        val = x;
        next = null;
    }
}



class Solution
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedNode node1 = new LinkedNode(1);
        LinkedNode node2 = new LinkedNode(2);
        LinkedNode node3 = new LinkedNode(3);
        LinkedNode node4 = new LinkedNode(3);
        LinkedNode node5 = new LinkedNode(3);
        LinkedNode node6 = new LinkedNode(3);
        LinkedNode node7 = new LinkedNode(4);
        LinkedNode node8 = new LinkedNode(5);

        node1.next = node2;
        node2.next = node3;
        node3.next = node4;
        node4.next = node5;
        node5.next = node6;
        node6.next = node7;
        node7.next = node8;
        node8.next = node1;

        LinkedNode after = check(node3);
        print_list(after);
    }


    public static void print_list(LinkedNode head)
    {   
        LinkedNode cur = head;
        do
        {
            System.out.print(head.val + " ");
            head = head.next;
        }
        while (cur!= head);//same question as the below
    }

    public static LinkedNode check(LinkedNode head)
    {   

        LinkedNode cur = head;
        do
        {   
            cur = cur.next;
        }   
        while(cur!=head);// this line is supposed to execute and exit at node4,since node4 is equal to node3(head)

        return cur;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.  In `check`, the method will keep looping as long as `cur != head`.  That means that when it finishes the loop, you will have `cur == head`, because `cur == head` is the only time it will exit the loop.  So basically, `check` will always return `head` (if it doesn't loop infinitely or crash).

Comment: Do While Blindly Executes The Code First Time It Doesnt Check For Any Condition

Comment: And can you tell me why check() function is used?

Comment: "since node4 is equal to node3(head)" <- no, it isn't. They are separate objects. They have the same `val`, but that's not what you're checking.

Comment: When my program reads at node4, which is equal to node3(head), it is supposed to exit at that moment, but why it can keep executing `do` block?

Comment: @ShankarShastri, I am confusing to `do-while` loop, so I wrote this program to test my idea. But I am still confusing.

Comment: Do While Blindly Executes The Code First Time. It Doesnt Check For Any Condition.It Starts To Check The Condition From Next Iteration.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, but node4 and node3(head), they have same`val`, same structure, same `next`. Then, how do we check if two Linkedlist nodes are same or not?

Comment: @ShankarShastri, I know `do-while` execute the `do` block statement at least once, then it starts to check the `while` condition. May be my question is not clear enough. I am wondering, when my program executes once, it reads node4. Node4 and node3(head), they have same val, same next,same structure. My `check` function should exit at here. But why it keeps looping?

Comment: You are comparing the references but not the values of the LinkedList

Comment: Ok. Got you. I just compared they values, but their references are different. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `node3.next = node4; node4.next = node5;` <- they don't have the same `next`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, you are right. I was just noticing their values, but Linkednode passes by reference not value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the objects by reference not value. Your logic is correct. Node 3 is never equal to Node 4, since they are separate objects, but what you want is to compare their value.

```
while(cur.val != head.val)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. You have the same idea as @ Shankar Shastri. Linkednode passes by reference not value. Thank you so much for your answer.